# How to sort an Array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this array:

```
array: [
    {id: 1, title: 'Thanos', content: '123'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Deadpool', content: '456'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Batman', content: '789'}
]
```

and I want it to be sorted by `title` key. How do I do that in `Javascript`?

Comment: That's not a 2D array. It's an array of objects.

Comment: see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I know it's difficult to understand if you don't know, that the original question was a different one and @jabaa pointed out that I was in fact looking for a different object. So I changed it. Thank you for your concern though.

Answer (score 1):

```
array.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates. That's not useful.

Comment: Although my question is a duplicate, I find this answer much more elegant than the answers in the original. Thank you

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov You can find this exact answer with a better description in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35092754/4645334 This question and answer are polluting this platform.

Comment: a bit harsh, but noted. I think there are worse things on this platform that are more polluting than duplicates though.